# Recursively sort an array

Tags: java, recursion

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        // reading csv file
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/andreeacondrut/Desktop/global_management.csv"));

        // create list to hold products

        List<Product2> product2List = new ArrayList<Product2>();

        String line = "";

        br.readLine();

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] productDetails = line.split(COMMA_DELIMITER);

            if (productDetails.length > 0) {
                // save the product2 information into product2 object
                Product2 productList = new Product2(productDetails[0], Double.parseDouble(productDetails[1]),
                        productDetails[2], productDetails[3], Integer.parseInt(productDetails[4]));

                product2List.add(productList);

            }
            Global_Inventory_Manager im = new Global_Inventory_Manager();
            im.sortArray(productDetails);
        }

        // print product
        for (Product2 e : product2List) {
            System.out.println(e.getName() + "," + e.getPrice() + "," + e.getDescription() + "," + e.getImagePath()
                    + "," + e.getQuantity());
        }

    } catch (Exception ee) {
        ee.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            System.out.println("ERROR occured while closing the BufferedReader.");
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    void sortArray(String[] productDetails) {
    int n = productDetails.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
            if (productDetails[j] > productDetails[j + 1]) {
                String temp = productDetails[j];
                productDetails[j] = productDetails[j + 1];
                productDetails[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to recursively sort an array of products by quantity and name. I am nowhere near success. Unfortunately any of the examples I have found I do not understand. This code gives me an error that says "Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, java.lang.String". Sorry if my code is formatted wrong, this is my first time using stack overflow and it wasn't reading the sorting method at the top. How do I fix that?

Comment: Is there any reason not to use a standard lib feature? If not, take a look at [`Arrays.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-java.lang.Object:A-).

Comment: You defined `String[] productDetails` and are trying to use the ">" operator on two elements of that array `productDetails[j] > productDetails[j + 1]` which are Strings. This is not allowed.

Comment: `String` is `Comparable`; there is no operator overloading in Java (so you can't use `>`, `<` or `==` for comparing object instances).

Comment: For comparing 2 strings have a look at [compareTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-) in the String class. As mentioned in other comments, you can't overload the operators in Java as you can do in C++

Comment: It's better to use [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of raw strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some improvements/changes that I'd suggest you to do:

1. change `productDetails[j] > productDetails[j + 1]` to `productDetails[j].compareTo(productDetails[j + 1]) > 0`. `String` in java is `Comparable`. You already have a compareTo defined for String objects. For details of how it works have a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-)
2. Design wise, why are you not using sorting that's already given to you by [Arrays.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-java.lang.Object:A-)
3. You are using something similar to [Bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). It has time complexity of `O(n^2)`. Why don't you use some sorting algorithm that takes `O(n*log(n))`? A better suggestion is to use [Arrays.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-java.lang.Object:A-) which has time complexity of `O(n*log(n))`.
4. Avoid putting everything in `main` method. Modularise your code.
5. Avoid wrapping the whole method in `try-catch`. A better thing to do is to just add a `throws` in the method signature.

Though this answer comments on many other things which you haven't asked, but I think your intention is to learn and improve and I'm just giving you a small help in that :)